# Python: using lambda as threading target causes strange behavior

Tags: python, multithreading, lambda

I am experiencing a strange behavior in Python. When I used a lambda as a target of a thread, the behavior was inconsistent.

The first example is like this:

```
import time,threading

locker= threading.RLock()

def func(obj):
  while obj['count']>0:
    with locker: print 'thread',obj,id(obj)
    obj['count']-= 1
    time.sleep(0.1)
  with locker: print 'finished',obj,id(obj)

def make_thread1():
  threads= []
  objs= {}
  for i in range(2):
    objs[i]= {}
    objs[i]['id']= i
    objs[i]['count']= (i+2)*2
    t= threading.Thread(name='func'+str(i), target=lambda: func(objs[i]))
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)
  return threads,objs

if __name__=='__main__':
  threads,objs= make_thread1()
  for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

There were two patterns of results.  One was

```
thread {'count': 4, 'id': 0} 139911658041704
thread {'count': 6, 'id': 1} 139911658041984
thread {'count': 3, 'id': 0} 139911658041704
thread {'count': 5, 'id': 1} 139911658041984
thread {'count': 4, 'id': 1} 139911658041984
thread {'count': 2, 'id': 0} 139911658041704
thread {'count': 3, 'id': 1} 139911658041984
thread {'count': 1, 'id': 0} 139911658041704
thread {'count': 2, 'id': 1} 139911658041984
finished {'count': 0, 'id': 0} 139911658041704
thread {'count': 1, 'id': 1} 139911658041984
finished {'count': 0, 'id': 1} 139911658041984
```

This is a result I expected.  However when running this code several times, sometimes it resulted like this:

```
thread {'count': 6, 'id': 1} 140389870428800
thread {'count': 5, 'id': 1} 140389870428800
thread {'count': 4, 'id': 1} 140389870428800
thread {'count': 3, 'id': 1} 140389870428800
thread {'count': 2, 'id': 1} 140389870428800
thread {'count': 1, 'id': 1} 140389870428800
finished {'count': 0, 'id': 1} 140389870428800
finished {'count': 0, 'id': 1} 140389870428800
```

When making the threads, `lambda:func(objs[0])` and `lambda:func(objs[1])` were defined as the target functions respectively, but actually both target functions were `lambda:func(objs[1])` (but different instances).

I cannot understand why this happened.

Well, one possibility would be that I was using a local variable `i` in making the lambda functions.  But it should be evaluated when `t.start()` was executed...?  Then why there were two patterns of the results?

For more investigation, I modified the code without lambda:

```
class TObj:
  def __init__(self):
    self.objs= None
  def f(self):
    func(self.objs)

def make_thread2():
  threads= []
  classes= {}
  for i in range(2):
    classes[i]= TObj()
    classes[i].objs= {}
    classes[i].objs['id']= i
    classes[i].objs['count']= (i+2)*2
    t= threading.Thread(name='func'+str(i), target=classes[i].f)
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)
  return threads,classes

if __name__=='__main__':
  threads,classes= make_thread2()
  for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

This code worked perfectly:

```
thread {'count': 4, 'id': 0} 140522771444352
thread {'count': 6, 'id': 1} 140522771445472
thread {'count': 3, 'id': 0} 140522771444352
thread {'count': 5, 'id': 1} 140522771445472
thread {'count': 2, 'id': 0} 140522771444352
thread {'count': 4, 'id': 1} 140522771445472
thread {'count': 1, 'id': 0} 140522771444352
thread {'count': 3, 'id': 1} 140522771445472
finished {'count': 0, 'id': 0} 140522771444352
thread {'count': 2, 'id': 1} 140522771445472
thread {'count': 1, 'id': 1} 140522771445472
finished {'count': 0, 'id': 1} 140522771445472
```

I want to understand the reasons why the inconsistency of the first code happened.

I also want to know how to make lambda functions in loops safely.  If the above problem was caused by using a loop variable `i` in a lambda function, we should avoid to generate lambda functions in loops.  It would be inconvenient; I could code like the latter one, but it was longer.  Are there any good ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idea to use lambda with loop variables is described in [Deferred evaluation with lambda in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11087047/deferred-evaluation-with-lambda-in-python)

We can use loop (local) variables in lambda by using default argument values.  In my case, making a lambda function like:

```
t= threading.Thread(name='func'+str(i), target=lambda i=i: func(objs[i]))
```

This worked as same as the second solution where a class object is used.

About the other point: when `Thread.start` evaluates the target?  It would depend on the system.  It could vary.  If there was a delay, it would be evaluated after `i` was incremented.  This would be a reason of the inconsistency.